# How to optimise query

Tags: mysql

This query returns all friends of logged in user, which is present in "network" table in below query. This maps `frd_id` and `mem_id` from these two tables.
I have optimized this query. but still it is taking time to get result.

Please suggest me optimized query for the same.

```
SELECT m.mem_id,m.profilenam,m.gender,m.photo_thumb,m.profile_type,n.frd_id as mem_id 
FROM `network` n 
left join members m on(n.frd_id=m.mem_id)
where ((n.frd_id = m.mem_id and n.mem_id=$uid) 
or (n.mem_id = m.mem_id and n.frd_id=$uid)) 
AND m.ban='n' 
AND m.deleted<>'Y' 
and profilenam like '%'
```

Comment: `profilenam like '%'` will match everything, surely.

Comment: i want to fetch all friends. so i write %.

Comment: Yes... but that would match *every record* -- so it's pointless having it there because it doesn't make the query more selective. I'd assume mysql optimizes it away but it may not.

Comment: @TZHX it does not - it wouldn't match `NULL`s

Comment: @zerkms if that's the goal, then surely `IS NOT NULL` would be a cheaper comparison?

Comment: @TZHX I don't know the goal, I'm not an OP. But I'm sure both will cause a fullscan (so they are equally terrible)

Comment: can i apply indexing for this.??

Comment: why don't you use a normal join instead a left join? This way you only get results when there is a member and you don't have to use the like clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.mem_id,m.profilenam,m.gender,m.photo_thumb,m.profile_type,m.mem_id 
FROM `network` n 
JOIN members m ON n.frd_id = m.mem_id
                  AND ( n.mem_id = $uid
                        OR ( n.mem_id = m.mem_id 
                             AND n.frd_id = $uid
                           )
                      )
WHERE m.profilenam IS NOT NULL
      AND m.ban = 'n' 
      AND m.deleted <> 'Y';
```